# Codeignier---sql database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, codeigniter

> [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Column 'TantraBackup00.GuildName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

```
SELECT 
    PK.KillerAccountName as CharacterName 
    ,count(PK.KillerAccountName) as totalkillings
    , TB.GuildName 
FROM PlayerKills as PK 
       LEFT JOIN 
    TantraBackup00 as TB ON PK.KillerAccountName = TB.CharacterName 
WHERE 
    PK.KillerCharacterName !='' 
GROUP BY PK.KillerAccountName
```

Answer (score 1):

To your question in the comments "*I did not get MIN(TB.GuildName), what the reson behind it, will you please explain?*":

It's required to use an **aggregate function** like `MIN()` because you're using a `GROUP BY` clause only on the `KillerAccountName` field.

Think of it this way, when you `GROUP BY` a field, all rows that share the same value of that field get collapsed into a single row. So you may ask, *what then happens to the data in the other columns of those rows that have different values from each other between different rows?* The answer is, you are unable to `SELECT` that data now because it's not possible to show more than one value of a column in a single row.

The only way it's possible again is to apply an **aggregation function** like nbk's answer does when he uses `MIN(TB.GuildName)` which gives you the *first* value (of the ordered set of values) in that column. (You could also use the `MAX()` aggregate function to get *last* value instead.)

Alternatively you can also include the `TB.GuildName` column in your `GROUP BY` clause which would then allow you to directly `SELECT` it since now every row will have a unique `TB.GuildName` in it too like so:

```
SELECT 
    PK.KillerAccountName as CharacterName 
    ,count(PK.KillerAccountName) as totalkillings
    , TB.GuildName
FROM PlayerKills as PK 
       LEFT JOIN 
    TantraBackup00 as TB ON PK.KillerAccountName = 
TB.CharacterName 
WHERE 
    PK.KillerCharacterName !='' 
GROUP BY PK.KillerAccountName, TB.GuildName
```

Note by adding the `TB.GuildName` field to the `GROUP BY` clause above, you may end up with more records than just grouping on `PK.KillerAccountName` since you're now telling SQL Server to collapse the rows on more specific criteria, the `PK.KillerAccountName` and `TB.GuildName`. So whether you want it to `GROUP BY` both columns so you can see all unique values of `TB.GuildName` or you don't care specifically which `TB.GuildName` is shown, as much, and the first (`MIN()`) one is sufficient, then you'd only want to group on `PK.KillerAccountName`. That's for you to decide based on your goals.

Answer (score 0):

Every column in the select has to be in the Group by or Have a [aggregation Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/sql/t-sql/functions/aggregate-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

It is dewscribed in the [manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
SELECT 
    PK.KillerAccountName as CharacterName 
    ,count(PK.KillerAccountName) as totalkillings
    , MIN(TB.GuildName)
FROM PlayerKills as PK 
       LEFT JOIN 
    TantraBackup00 as TB ON PK.KillerAccountName = TB.CharacterName 
WHERE 
    PK.KillerCharacterName !='' 
GROUP BY PK.KillerAccountName
```

Would be working, of course as we can't see your data, you have to figure it out your self.